# Using D3DPT_LINELIST to render 3D lines

Tags: c++, direct3d

When attempting to draw a line in 3D space with `D3DPT_LINELIST`, then Direct3D gives me an error about an invalid vertex declaration, saying that it cannot be converted to an `FVF`. I am using the same vertex declaration and shader/stream setup as for my `D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST` rendering which works absolutely correctly.

How can I use `D3DPT_LINELIST` to render some lines in 3D space?

Here's my raw Draw call.

```
D3DCALL(device->SetVertexDeclaration(VertexDecl));
D3DCALL(device->SetStreamSource(1, PerBoneBuffer.get(), 0, sizeof(PerInstanceData)));
D3DCALL(device->SetStreamSourceFreq(1, D3DSTREAMSOURCE_INSTANCEDATA | 1));
D3DCALL(device->SetStreamSource(0, LineVerts, 0, sizeof(D3DXVECTOR3)));
D3DCALL(device->SetStreamSourceFreq(0, D3DSTREAMSOURCE_INDEXEDDATA | lines.size()));
D3DCALL(device->SetIndices(LineIndices));
PerInstanceData* data;
std::vector<Wide::Render::Line*> lines_vec(lines.begin(), lines.end());
D3DCALL(PerBoneBuffer->Lock(0, lines.size() * sizeof(PerInstanceData), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&data), D3DLOCK_DISCARD));
std::for_each(lines.begin(), lines.end(), [&](Wide::Render::Line* ptr) {
    data->Color = D3DXColor(ptr->Colour);
    D3DXMATRIXA16 Translate, Scale, Rotate;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&Translate, ptr->Start.x, ptr->Start.y, ptr->Start.z);
    D3DXMatrixScaling(&Scale, ptr->Scale, 1, 1);
    D3DXMatrixRotationQuaternion(&Rotate, &D3DQuaternion(ptr->Rotation));
    data->World = Scale * Rotate * Translate;
});
D3DCALL(PerBoneBuffer->Unlock());
D3DCALL(device->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPRIMITIVETYPE::D3DPT_LINELIST, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1));
```

Here's my vertex declaration:

```
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 BasicMeshVertices[] = {
    {0, 0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION, 0},
    {1, 0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 0},
    {1, 16, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 1},
    {1, 32, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 2},
    {1, 48, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 3},
    {1, 64, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_COLOR, 0},
    D3DDECL_END()
};
D3DCALL(Device->CreateVertexDeclaration(
    BasicMeshVertices,
    PointerToPointer(BasicMeshVertexDecl)
));
```

The `LineIndices` are just `0, 1` and the `LineVerts` are just `{0,0,0}` and `{1,0,0}`, to represent a unit 3D line along the X axis.

Comment: Can you post your code which calls CreateVertexDeclaration(), SetVertexDeclaration() and the relevant vertex shader code?

Comment: @Asaf: Gimme a sec to find those particular pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you're actually using a vertex shader (didn't see code for it - is it a fixed pipeline?). I don't know what might cause the difference between triangles and a line list, but the error you're getting means that your vertex declaration cannot be converted to the older FVF.

From [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/58941083/8/Vertex-Declarations) (page 177 - 5.8.1: Fixed-Function Declarations):

> When using the ﬁxed-function pipeline with a vertex declaration, the appropriate vertex components must each be mapped to a particular usage. You can use multiple streams, but the vertices must conform to the order and type constraints of the FVF codes described in section 5.7.

And from section 5.7:

> The vertex components are laid out in memory in the same order as the vertex components listed in the table, starting with the position component.

The table is simply the list of `D3DFVF_*` constants from the header files.

So in your case - try moving the color component to be before the tex coords components in the PerInstanceData (stream 1) struct.

Comment: I am using a shader, actually... but as you correctly point out, it is not set to the device at the time of drawing, which is probably the mistake in question. Give me a few hours to test it and I shall report back.